# Are there any options to update to Monterey, but not to the newest Ventura?

Tags: macos, big-sur, monterey, ventura

How to update to Monterey without Ventura?

I have an M1 MacBook Pro with Big Sur, version 11.5.2. I personally prefer not to update, but I just realize some problem, include but not limit to software support, App Store's app requirement.

I decided to update directly to Monterey, people said Monterey is just Big Sur with bug fixes, and runs well, but Ventura got a lot of criticism (slow, lots of bugs, suddenly stops, slow performance, more battery cost).

When I checking my System software update, I could only install Ventura as the newest version, not Monterey. I'm just wondering are there any options that I could go directly to Monterey?

Comment: You can download Monterey from the App Store: https://apps.apple.com/by/app/macos-monterey/id1576738294?mt=12

Comment: @lhf um, Where? I cannot find Monterey at my App Store, that link seems doesn't works

Comment: Ironically, I wouldn't put that much store in "what people on the internet are saying". No one posts "Everything is working well!" -- they only post when there are problems, and there are many causes, not all of them the OS. I haven't had any performance issues with Ventura on M1 and M2. Plus, we are now on .5 of Ventura, so many of the early bugs will have been worked out.

Comment: The link provided by @lhf works fine for me, opens the App Store page for Monterey, and I'm also on an M1 MBP. Ensure that it opens first in Safari and then opens the App Store from there. If you open it in a different browser it might not automatically open the App Store. But I agree with benwiggy Ventura at 13.5 is stable (always has been IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides download links for each version of macOS: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683

The link for macOS Monterey is: https://apps.apple.com/by/app/macos-monterey/id1576738294?mt=12